# Duplicating functions

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

**Whenever I call the Instantiate function it duplicates every single function with it and doubles every number**

```
    private Button[] Checks;
    public GameObject tni;//TextAndInput
    public int Coins;

    public TMPro.TextMeshProUGUI Score;
    private void Start()
    {
        Checks = GetComponentsInChildren<Button>();
       foreach(Button button in Checks)
       {
            button.onClick.AddListener(Add);
       }
        
    }
    private void Update()
    {
        Score.SetText(Coins.ToString());
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            Duplicate();
        }
    }
    public void Add()
    {

        Coins++;
    }
    public void Duplicate()
    {
        GameObject duplicate = GameObject.Instantiate(tni);
        duplicate.transform.position=new Vector3(tni.transform.position.x, tni.transform.position.y-100, tni.transform.position.z);
        duplicate.transform.SetParent(GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Canvas").transform, false);
        Button ButtonDuplicate = GetComponentInChildren<Button>();
        ButtonDuplicate.onClick.AddListener( () => Add() );
    }
```

** For example, the add function adds 2 on the first button and 1 on the duplicated button. and when I duplicate the buttons it will duplicate first the 1 button then when If I duplicate again it will duplicate another 2 so now they are 4 buttons and If I duplicate them again they will be 8 and so on
If you know how to fix it please tell me
**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem line seems to be

```
Button ButtonDuplicate = GetComponentInChildren<Button>();
```

you always do this on the very same object (the one this script is attached to) so

```
ButtonDuplicate.onClick.AddListener( () => Add() );
```

always adds an additional callback to `Add` for the first button that is found among the children of this object.

---

It seems to me you rather wanted to do

```
Button ButtonDuplicate = duplicate.GetComponentInChildren<Button>();
```

in order to get the component of the button you just spawned instead.

---

**Update**

To your comment about the position

In

```
duplicate.transform.position=new Vector3(tni.transform.position.x, tni.transform.position.y-100, tni.transform.position.z);
```

you always take the same `tni` position which is never changed and from there go `-100` in `Y`.

Instead rather store the last spawned position e.g. like

```
private Vector3 currentSpawnPos;

private void Start ()
{
    ...

    currentSpawnPos = tni.transform.position - Vector3.up * 100;
}

public void Duplicate()
{
    ...
    duplicate.transform.position=new Vector3(currentSpawnPos);
    currentSpawnPos -= Vector3.up * 100;
    ...
}
```

Or actually instead of calculating that on your own you could use a [`VerticalLayoutGroup`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/manual/script-VerticalLayoutGroup.html) and just add your buttons and they will be automatically be placed below each other

Comment: But Know it puts the first one -100 on the y axis then all the rest are in the exact same position

Comment: Well you always take the same position of `tni` which doesn't move and go `-100` from there ... rather store the last spawn position, go from there and update it after the spawn .. see the update at the bottom